# PowerShell Loading Animation

Tags: powershell

I would like to create a GUI that shows a loading bar while a job is running in the background. For simplicity, I've made the job an infinite loop so it should always be running. I've only included necessary parts of the code:

```
$Label = new-object system.windows.forms.Label
$Label.Font = 'Ariel,12pt'
$Label.Text = ""
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Label.Location = new-object system.drawing.size(50,10)
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

$LoadingAnimation = @(".....","0....",".0...","..0..","...0.","....0",".....")
$AnimationCount = 0

$test = start-job -Name Job -ScriptBlock { for($t=1;$t -gt 0; $t++){} }
while ($test.JobStateInfo.State -eq "Running")
{
    $Label.Text = $LoadingAnimation[($AnimationCount)]
    $AnimationCount++
    if ($AnimationCount -eq $LoadingAnimation.Count){$AnimationCount = 0}
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}
```

Upon testing this code in the console, just using Write-Host instead of $Label.Text, it works just fine. What needs to be done differently to get this to work in a windows form created by PowerShell?

Comment: Take a look at [Running ProgressBar on Powershell-GUI (System.Windows.Forms)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/97017441-6a0a-46be-8986-192eadf1f130/running-progressbar-on-powershellgui-systemwindowsforms-when-form-loaded?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: @LotPings This looks very promising, thank you!

Comment: After playing with that a little bit, it does show a nice progress bar. Unfortunately, I'm trying to make my own. Not use a generic one provided by Windows. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the little details of the script, I found the problem. This is how I activated my form:

```
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

This caused the script to stop when the form was launched, ShowDialog stops the script to allow interaction. The fix was:

```
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.Show()
```

Using Form.Show lets the script to continue to run because it doesn't require interaction.

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell, you can create all sorts of status, including multi-level, using `Write-Progress`.  Don't forget to call with -Completed when done (a common mistake I see).

`Get-Help Write-Progress`

Comment: I have used write-progress in the past, but that was displayed in a powershell console. I'm trying to create a custom loading bar in the middle of a windows form that is created and ran by a powershell script. I don't believe write-progress is what i'm looking for, I could be wrong